# how to store SQLite file in a public phone directory

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I would like to ask you if there is way to store a SQLite file into a public phone directory so afterwards it could be downloaded to PC.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try `path_provider` .

You can store files on app directory.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider

Comment: even on Android ?

Comment: yes appDirectory is: /data/user/0/<my-app>/app_flutter